# Xcode 5 UINavigationBar TintColor property not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I want to develop apps for iOS 6 and 7.

Basically i started with Xocde 5 including `Storyboard` and `ARC` in my project.

Now, i want to change color of `NavigationBar` from `Storyboard` but storyboard shows only `BarTintColor` property (which is available only for `iOS 7`) and `Storyboard` not showing `TintColor` property for `NavigationBar` (to change color in `iOS 6`).

How should i change color of `NavigationBar` in `iOS 6` using same `Storyboard` ?

I am also facing same problem for `UITabBar` Shows only `BarTintColor` property and not `TintColor` property of `iOS 6`

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your appDelegate

```
#import "yourMainViewController"

yourMainViewController = [[yourMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourMainViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.yourMainViewController];

NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yourColore];
    navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}else {
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor yourColore];
}

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Comment: I have multiple pages in my app, i need to write this in my all pages, instead of doing this is there any other way ??